# きのう、私は VS. 私はきのう

Tags: word-order

I was wondering if both ways are grammatically correct, when starting a sentence.
I think starting like : "きのう、私は..." would put more emphasise on the fact that what ever follows happened yesterday, while "私はきのう..." puts more weight on what happened and giving the extra information that whatever it was, it happened yesterday.

I would appreciate any sort of input on that matter :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, exactly as you said. Both are perfectly valid ways of starting a sentence. The difference in nuance is basically the same as the difference between "Yesterday, I did X" and "I did X yesterday" in English.